Unable to write data to Iceberg table using Spark Streaming
I have a local docker setup of spark-iceberg, rest catalog and minio. When I am running the spark streaming code, it is able to read from a kafka topic and attempts writing to an Iceberg table. I can see the metadata file getting created on minio but no data files. What am I possibly doing wrong? I dont see any error messages either. I have tried various output modes, triggers etc.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json, min, max, avg, window
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, DoubleType, StringType, TimestampType

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Kafka-Iceberg-Stream-Processor").getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    schema = StructType([
        StructField("BTC_EUR", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("BTC_INR", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("BTC_USD", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("ETH_EUR", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("ETH_INR", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("ETH_USD", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True)
    ])

    kafka_df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.16:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "crypto") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()

    parsed_df = kafka_df.selectExpr(
        "CAST(value AS STRING) AS value",
        "timestamp"
    ).withColumn("parsed_json", from_json(col("value"), schema)) \
        .select(
        col("parsed_json.BTC_EUR").alias("BTC_EUR"),
        col("parsed_json.BTC_INR").alias("BTC_INR"),
        col("parsed_json.BTC_USD").alias("BTC_USD"),
        col("parsed_json.ETH_EUR").alias("ETH_EUR"),
        col("parsed_json.ETH_INR").alias("ETH_INR"),
        col("parsed_json.ETH_USD").alias("ETH_USD"),
        col("parsed_json.timestamp").alias("event_time"),
        col("timestamp").alias("processing_time")
    )

    windowed_df = parsed_df \
        .withWatermark("event_time", "1 minute") \
        .groupBy(window(col("event_time"), "5 minutes", "5 minutes")) \
        .agg(
        max("BTC_EUR").alias("max_BTC_EUR"),
        min("BTC_EUR").alias("min_BTC_EUR"),
        avg("BTC_EUR").alias("avg_BTC_EUR"),
        max("BTC_INR").alias("max_BTC_INR"),
        min("BTC_INR").alias("min_BTC_INR"),
        avg("BTC_INR").alias("avg_BTC_INR"),
        max("BTC_USD").alias("max_BTC_USD"),
        min("BTC_USD").alias("min_BTC_USD"),
        avg("BTC_USD").alias("avg_BTC_USD"),
        max("ETH_EUR").alias("max_ETH_EUR"),
        min("ETH_EUR").alias("min_ETH_EUR"),
        avg("ETH_EUR").alias("avg_ETH_EUR"),
        max("ETH_INR").alias("max_ETH_INR"),
        min("ETH_INR").alias("min_ETH_INR"),
        avg("ETH_INR").alias("avg_ETH_INR"),
        max("ETH_USD").alias("max_ETH_USD"),
        min("ETH_USD").alias("min_ETH_USD"),
        avg("ETH_USD").alias("avg_ETH_USD")
    ).withColumn("window_start", col("window.start")) \
        .withColumn("window_end", col("window.end")) \
        .drop("window") \
        .select("window_start",
                "window_end",
                "max_BTC_EUR",
                "min_BTC_EUR",
                "avg_BTC_EUR",
                "max_BTC_INR",
                "min_BTC_INR",
                "avg_BTC_INR",
                "max_BTC_USD",
                "min_BTC_USD",
                "avg_BTC_USD",
                "max_ETH_EUR",
                "min_ETH_EUR",
                "avg_ETH_EUR",
                "max_ETH_INR",
                "min_ETH_INR",
                "avg_ETH_INR",
                "max_ETH_USD",
                "min_ETH_USD",
                "avg_ETH_USD")

    # Create the table if it doesn't exist
    spark.sql("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.crypto_metrics5 (
            window_start TIMESTAMP,
            window_end TIMESTAMP,
            max_BTC_EUR DOUBLE,
            min_BTC_EUR DOUBLE,
            avg_BTC_EUR DOUBLE,
            max_BTC_INR DOUBLE,
            min_BTC_INR DOUBLE,
            avg_BTC_INR DOUBLE,
            max_BTC_USD DOUBLE,
            min_BTC_USD DOUBLE,
            avg_BTC_USD DOUBLE,
            max_ETH_EUR DOUBLE,
            min_ETH_EUR DOUBLE,
            avg_ETH_EUR DOUBLE,
            max_ETH_INR DOUBLE,
            min_ETH_INR DOUBLE,
            avg_ETH_INR DOUBLE,
            max_ETH_USD DOUBLE,
            min_ETH_USD DOUBLE,
            avg_ETH_USD DOUBLE
        ) USING iceberg
    """)

    print(spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN rest.db").show())
    print(windowed_df.printSchema())
    # Write stream data to Iceberg
    query = windowed_df.writeStream \
        .outputMode("complete") \
        .format("iceberg") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/spark/checkpoints/crypto_metrics5") \
        .toTable("rest.db.crypto_metrics5")

    query.awaitTermination()

spark submit command
spark-submit \
    --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.7.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.4 \
    --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest.type=rest \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest.uri=http://rest:8181 \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest.warehouse=s3://warehouse \
    --conf spark.sql.defaultCatalog=rest \
    test.py

